# Clear dropdown list and/or text box content when we hide/show using JavaScript When they are selected alternatively

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to show either dropdown or text box when I select options from a select box.

Dropdown Box where I select either one option:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Lessor Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select onchange="showDiv(this)" class="form-control" id="lessor_name" name="lessor_name" required>
            <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
            <option value="Company">Company</option>
            <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
        </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

When I select `Company` below `div` will appear,

```
<div class="form-group" name="vehiclelist" id="vehiclelist" style="display:none;">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Vehicle Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select class="form-control" id="vehicle_list" name="vehicle_list" >
        <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>                                               
    </div>
</div>
```

When I select `Vendor` below `div` will appear

```
<div class="form-group" name="vendor_vehicle" id="vendor_vehicle" style="display:none;">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Vendor Vehicle Num</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vendor_vehicle_num" name="vendor_vehicle_num" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my JavaScript

```
function showDiv(select){
 if(select.value=="Company"){
  document.getElementById('vehiclelist').style.display = "block";
 } else{
  document.getElementById('vehiclelist').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('vehiclelist').value="";
 }
 if(select.value=="Vendor"){
  document.getElementById('vendor_vehicle').style.display = "block";
 } else{
  document.getElementById('vendor_vehicle').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('vendor_vehicle').value="";
 }
 }
```

Above Mentioned Code is working Great for me. But the problem is when I first select the `Vendor` and will type any text in `textbox`, if I wish to select `Company` in dropdown list the inserted text will remain the same in `vendor` textbox.

How to clear the text box in `Vendor` and Dropdown box selected in `Company` via JavaScript when they are selected alternatively?

Thank You In Advance

Comment: only one can select --so only one can display

Comment: Hi @Kirataka if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your referencing the wrong IDs I think. Try this and let me know if it is fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
</style>

<body>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Lessor Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select onchange="showDiv(this)" class="form-control" id="lessor_name" name="lessor_name" required>
            <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
            <option value="Company">Company</option>
            <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
        </select>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" name="vehiclelist" id="vehiclelist" style="display:none;">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Vehicle Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select class="form-control" id="vehicle_list" name="vehicle_list" >
        <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>                                               
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" name="vendor_vehicle" id="vendor_vehicle" style="display:none;">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Vendor Vehicle Num</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vendor_vehicle_num" name="vendor_vehicle_num" >
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>

function showDiv(select){
 if(select.value=="Company"){
  document.getElementById('vehiclelist').style.display = "block";
 } else{
  document.getElementById('vehiclelist').style.display = "none";

 }
 if(select.value=="Vendor"){
  document.getElementById('vendor_vehicle').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('vendor_vehicle_num').value="";
 } else{
  document.getElementById('vendor_vehicle').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('vendor_vehicle').value="";
 }
 }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Ya . U r right bro. I was passing the wrong ID in JS. Thank You.  Its working now.